# What does 'cataloginventory/item_options/' means?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog

What does `'cataloginventory/item_options/'` means in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` class?

could you please explain briefly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at other core classes such as `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Action_Attribute_Tab_Inventory` you will see calls to:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::XML_PATH_ITEM . $field, $this->getStoreId());
```

so `XML_PATH_ITEM` is a config path which is appended to to create a full valid `getStoreConfig()` path.  You can see the config defined in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/system.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <cataloginventory translate="label" module="cataloginventory">
            ...
            <groups>
                ...
                <item_options translate="label comment">
                    ...
                    <fields>
                        <manage_stock translate="label">
                            ...
                        </manage_stock>
                        <!-- more nodes here -->
                    </fields>
                </item_options>
            </groups>
        </cataloginventory>
    </sections>
</config>
```

So `XML_PATH_ITEM` targets the `item_options` node  with `manage_stock` or another nodes value appended to create the full config path.